# project not running in Eclipse no errors

Tags: spring, eclipse, tomcat

I have a Spring project that I am running in Tomcat in Eclipse. This was working till yesterday. All of a sudden it does not look like Tomcat is loading the project although it shows as published and synchronized. I see no errors in Tomcat logs. Any insights on why this is happening?

Comment: What *do* you see in the Tomcat logs? There's not enough information here to make any conclusions.

Comment: As I said when I go to the logs for Tomcat, I don't see anything. Logs are from a day ago. In Eclipse console, I don't see anything except that the project is not loaded. I agree not enough info and that is the issue I am facing, there is nothing in the logs that can guide me. Are Tomcat server logs same whether you start it in Eclipse or standalone?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who might run into this issue. I right clicked on project, click on properties, go to Deployment Assembly and added "Build Maven dependencies". I added them before and the project was loaded with no issues. When I checked it after this issue started happening, the "Maven dependencies entry in "Deployment Assembly" disappeared.

[image]